# GeoJson Loop no close

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to query through a collection of tweets that have GeoJson data as follow:

```
[ [ [ -63.39386, -41.035009 ], [ -62.39386, -33.260144 ], [ -54.665826, -33.260144 ], [ -56.665836, -41.035009 ] ] ]
```

using `$geoWithin` I want to filter using a Bounding_box the problem is: I don't get any results even though the coordinates above are contained in my bounding_box.

Trying to get some light in the problem I used https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/ to create some GeoJson data to see if it works and yes, it always works, for example, I get the coordinates such as

```
                                     [[[-69.40602388, -28.3114053673],
                                     [-68.7425288674, -28.3114053673],
                                     [-68.7425288674, -27.7163373156],
                                     [-69.40602388, -27.7163373156],
                                     [-69.40602388, -28.3114053673]]].
```

Trying to understand why it works when using https://boundingbox.klokantech.com/ and not with the collection I discover that with the collection coordinates I get an error:`pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Loop is not closed: [ [ -63.39386, -41.035009 ], [ -62.39386, -33.260144 ], [ -54.665826, -33.260144 ], [ -56.665836, -41.035009 ] ]` when trying to use this coordinates as a filter with `$geoWithin.`.. so that means that the problem is the collection coordinates? but those are from twitter I can not do anything about that. Maybe there is a way to close the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that GeoJson data requires to close the loop with the same point that you opened it.

For: `[ [ [ -63.39386, -41.035009 ], [ -62.39386, -33.260144 ], [ -54.665826, -33.260144 ], [ -56.665836, -41.035009 ] ] ]`

I have to add [ -63.39386, -41.035009 ]at the end so it became: `[ [ [ -63.39386, -41.035009 ], [ -62.39386, -33.260144 ], [ -54.665826, -33.260144 ], [ -56.665836, -41.035009 ],[ -63.39386, -41.035009 ] ] ]`